# Linux symlink all files in directory is adding '*'

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

I'm trying to symlink all files in a directory to a target directory, by doing:

```
ln -s /directory/* /target-directory
```

Problem is when I go into the target-directory, I'm seeing this '*', an asterisk in quotes, instead of all the files in the first directory. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is there really a non-hidden file/directory in /directory/ ?

Comment: I get a different result, for me the command works as expected.

Comment: Please add some more information: what type of shell is that you are using? What distribution?

Comment: Did you start `bash` with `bash -f` or did a `set -f` or `set -o noglob` after starting the shell & before running `ln` command?

Comment: @arkascha using bash, distro is Arch Linux.

Comment: @anishsane I didn't use any of those commands before running `ln`

Comment: OK. try running `set +f` & then run the `ln` command... Also, see if `set -o` output has `noglob          on`

Comment: @anishsane ran `set +f`, same thing happened. Also ran `set -o`, got `noglob          off`

Comment: If you see `*` that means globbing could not expand any filename. Are there any files in the source? Are they hidden (i.e. starting with a dot)?

Comment: @JürgenHötzel yeah, I've added just a simple html file in the source folder named "index.html"... :/

Comment: So what is the output of: `ls /directory/*`?

Comment: @JürgenHötzel your question led me to figure this out. My actual command was `sudo ln -s home/user/Documents/website/* /srv/http/website`. I did `ls home/user/Documents/website` which gave me "No such file or directory". Looks like I forgot the forward slash in front of home and that did it... can't believe it! Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, what'd happen when you run `ln -s /directory/* /target-directory` is that the shell would expand `/directory/*` into a list of the (currently existing, visible) files in /directory/, and then pass that to `ln` in its argument list. The result would be equivalent to something like `ln -s /directory/file1.txt /directory/file3.pdf /directory/file3.c /target-directory`. Note that the `ln` command would not see the "*", and so would not include it in either the link source or target name.

Since "*" is being used as the link name, it's not getting expanded. There are a couple of reasons this might happen:

- You might have the `noglob` shell option set. But you said in the comments that's not the case.
- The shell expansion might not have matched any files, in which case the shell will simply pass it unchanged to `ln`, giving the result you describe. You said you created a file in the source directory, but did you re-test after doing that? Another possibility is that there's a typo in the directory path, so it's not finding a matching directory (let alone any files in it).

Oh, one more note: you said when you go to the target directory, you see an asterisk *in quotes*. Exactly how are you looking? Because if you're just using `ls`, it should not include quotes in the listing unless they're actually part of the filename. [Edit: Mark Plotnick pointed out that some versions of GNU `ls` *do* add quotes to some filenames.]  I have no idea how the command you gave could add quotes to the filename.

Comment: Certain versions of GNU `ls` output quotes around filenames that may need quoting in order to be pasted to the shell. Details at [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That'd explain it; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not create the destination directory and do

`ln -sd ./source ./destination`

Comment: The OP wants to symlink the files, not the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the failglob option, you will get an error message if expansion of * is not possible.

```
shopt -s failglob
```